# Unity 3D character c# script, jump not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have this first person player controller c# script, (I followed brackeys' tutorial) and I have the jump input coded, basically word for word, but for some reason it doesn't jump, instead once I start the game, the player just floats up infinitely, which is definitely not what I want. Here's the script incase any of you know how to fix it(sorry if the error is a typo or something, but this would help greatly):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;

    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -9.81f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public Transform groundCheck;

    public float jumpHeight = 3f;

    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;
    
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is VERY similar to what is found here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html

Maybe this is a silly question, but is your PlayerMovement script attached to your game object? The issue may not be with the code, but with your scene whether by forgetting to attach scripts or forgetting to define a variable in the editor. One way to test this hypothesis is to copy-paste the code at that link into your controller and see if you get the same behavior.

Comment: Function `Update()` in Unity very important, and consider writing code on it. Do you try to detect jump and handed it to function, Jump trigger in Update ->Call to function Move(). To clarify, I think you need to see more on Tutorial of Brackey on:
https://github.com/Brackeys/2D-Character-Controller